# Ruby Bug - Segmentation fault at POINTER ruby 2.5.3 p105

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

**I was working on upgrading a project from Rails 3.1 to rails 5.2
during this I updated Ruby Version from 2.0.0 to 2.5.3
after finishing a lot of upgrading steps I was able to run Rails server
now when I try to test APIs locally through insomnia (Postman Alternative)
I faced this error
any informations? or guidelines?**

```
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/local_environment.rb:52: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000110
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin18]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.
```

```
-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0026 p:---- s:0140 e:000139 CFUNC  :each_object
c:0025 p:0027 s:0135 e:000134 METHOD /Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/local_environment.rb:52
c:0024 p:0065 s:0130 e:000129 METHOD /Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/local_environment.rb:125
c:0023 p:0054 s:0125 e:000124 METHOD /Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/local_environment.rb:80
c:0022 p:0009 s:0120 e:000119 METHOD /Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/local_environment.rb:32
c:0021 p:0019 s:0116 e:000115 BLOCK  /Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/default_sourc [FINISH]
```

```
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/threading/agent_thread.rb:14:in `block in create'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/agent.rb:707:in `block in start_worker_thread'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/agent.rb:680:in `deferred_work!'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/agent.rb:661:in `catch_errors'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/agent.rb:681:in `block in deferred_work!'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:506:in `disable_all_tracing'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/agent.rb:682:in `block (2 levels) in deferred_work!'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/agent.rb:928:in `connect'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/agent.rb:809:in `connect_to_server'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/connect/request_builder.rb:34:in `connect_payload'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/manager.rb:218:in `to_collector_hash'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/manager.rb:195:in `flattened'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/manager.rb:195:in `inject'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/manager.rb:195:in `each'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/manager.rb:197:in `block in flattened'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/manager.rb:197:in `each'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/manager.rb:199:in `block (2 levels) in flattened'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/manager.rb:199:in `instance_eval'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/default_source.rb:131:in `block in dispatcher'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/local_environment.rb:32:in `discovered_dispatcher'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/local_environment.rb:80:in `discover_dispatcher'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/local_environment.rb:125:in `check_for_unicorn'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/local_environment.rb:52:in `find_class_in_object_space'
/Users/monier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@programmer_app_2/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.7.0.359/lib/new_relic/local_environment.rb:52:in `each_object'
```

```
-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 rax: 0x0000000000000100 rbx: 0x00007febe6f91ad0 rcx: 0x00007fff8d178a40
 rdx: 0x0000000000000000 rdi: 0x00007fff8d178a40 rsi: 0x00007febe6f91ad0
 rbp: 0x00007ffeedb47cf0 rsp: 0x00007ffeedb47ca8  r8: 0x0000000000000000
  r9: 0x00007febe6f91ad0 r10: 0x007fffffffffffff r11: 0x0000004000000000
 r12: 0x00007ffeedb47db0 r13: 0x0000002000000000 r14: 0x00007ffeedb47d50
 r15: 0x0000000000000000 rip: 0x00007fff6310644e rfl: 0x0000000000010206
```

```
-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x00000001022a4827 rb_vm_bugreport + 135
1   libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010212b128 rb_bug_context + 472
2   libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102217e21 sigsegv + 81
3   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff6334db1d _sigtramp + 29
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6310644e _dispatch_mgr_queue_push + 41
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff630fc50e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff63108567 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
7   Security                            0x00007fff384d6661 _ZN8Security12KeychainCore14StorageManager14tickleKeychainEPNS0_12KeychainImplE + 485
8   Security                            0x00007fff382a9374 _ZN8Security12KeychainCore12KCCursorImpl4nextERNS0_4ItemE + 352
9   Security                            0x00007fff384786a1 _ZN8Security12KeychainCore14IdentityCursor4nextERNS_10SecPointerINS0_8IdentityEEE + 217
10  Security                            0x00007fff3849d1ef SecIdentitySearchCopyNext + 155
11  Security                            0x00007fff384a8504 _Z23SecItemCopyMatching_osxPK14__CFDictionaryPPKv + 261
12  Security                            0x00007fff384abd50 SecItemCopyMatching + 338
13  Heimdal                             0x00007fff4dd72f43 keychain_query + 531
14  Heimdal                             0x00007fff4dd70b8c hx509_certs_find + 92
15  Heimdal                             0x00007fff4dd2f592 _krb5_pk_find_cert + 466
16  GSS                                 0x00007fff2e74c98b _gsspku2u_acquire_cred + 619
17  GSS                                 0x00007fff2e731bbc gss_acquire_cred + 940
18  libpq.5.dylib                       0x00000001035176e3 pg_GSS_have_cred_cache + 54
19  libpq.5.dylib                       0x0000000103505eb0 PQconnectPoll + 6356
20  libpq.5.dylib                       0x0000000103503026 connectDBComplete + 231
21  libpq.5.dylib                       0x00000001035031ad PQconnectdb + 36
22  pg_ext.bundle                       0x00000001034c4181 gvl_PQconnectdb_skeleton + 17
23  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102251a92 rb_thread_call_without_gvl + 82
24  pg_ext.bundle                       0x00000001034c415d gvl_PQconnectdb + 45
25  pg_ext.bundle                       0x00000001034c9289 pgconn_init + 121
26  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010229ee2d vm_call0_body + 557
27  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010229fb48 rb_call0 + 152
28  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010228b261 rb_funcallv + 49
29  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102199059 rb_class_s_new + 41
30  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010229815b vm_call_cfunc + 283
31  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102281cad vm_exec_core + 11805
32  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102292a2e vm_exec + 142
33  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010229fb48 rb_call0 + 152
34  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010228b261 rb_funcallv + 49
35  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102199059 rb_class_s_new + 41
36  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010229815b vm_call_cfunc + 283
37  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102281cad vm_exec_core + 11805
38  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102292a2e vm_exec + 142
39  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010229fd04 invoke_block_from_c_bh + 372
40  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010228dd3e rb_yield + 158
41  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010219899e rb_obj_tap + 14
42  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010229815b vm_call_cfunc + 283
43  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010228126d vm_exec_core + 9181
44  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102292a2e vm_exec + 142
45  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010217ac61 rb_load_internal0 + 337
46  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010217b499 rb_require_internal + 1609
47  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010217acf8 rb_f_require + 24
48  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x000000010229815b vm_call_cfunc + 283
49  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102281cad vm_exec_core + 11805
50  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102292a2e vm_exec + 142
51  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x00000001021350a1 ruby_exec_internal + 177
52  libruby.2.5.dylib                   0x0000000102134f98 ruby_run_node + 56
53  ruby                                0x00000001020b4f2f main + 79
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this on 2.5.3. But a question - why use 2.5.3 when there is 2.5.6 available? Perhaps they fixed some bug in the meantime. I'd recommend trying.

Comment: @katafrakt  
actually it's Business Decision related to a lot of factors. 
I can't change the version for sorry

Comment: But you can at least check if segmentation fault still exists in 2.5.6, I guess. If it does, it's worth digging why. If not -then the business decision was simply a wrong one.

Comment: @katafrakt
I will give it a try